# How do I use UNetbootin to install Ubuntu without getting unmet dependencies?

Tags: 10.04, dependencies, unetbootin

I am trying to install Ubuntu 15.x without a bootable USB thumbdrive using UNetbootin. I was not able to install UNetbootin:

```
sudo apt-get install -f unetbootin
```

It resulted in unmet dependencies, and here is the exact error text:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
unetbootin: Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not installable
              Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.6.1) but it is not installable
              Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not installable
              Depends: p7zip-full but it is not installable
              Recommends: extlinux but it is not installable
E: Broken packages
```

I currently have Ubuntu 10.04 on my system.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 and 15.10 are old and unsupported like your current Ubuntu 10.04 and you will run into similar problems like this one with it. You should install a supported release like 16.04 LTS or 16.10 instead.

Comment: Why do you want to install without a CD/DVD disk or USB flash drive? Depending on your reply to this, I can suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 10.04 LTS has passed end of life and is no longer supported. I think this is one reason why you have problems to install UNetbootin. Ubuntu 15.04 and 15.10 have also passed end of life. So you should aim at another version of Ubuntu.

If your computer is as old as the operating system (or older), it is a good idea to get a flavour of Ubuntu with a lighter desktop environment, Lubuntu, Ubuntu MATE or Xubuntu. And I would recommend the version 16.04.1 LTS.